# How can I check #ifdef in a DLL project, when the #define is in the executable project using the dll?

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015

I have a C++ Visual Studio 2015 project consisting of 
1 Windows API executable, 1 windows console executable, and 1 dll shared by both executables.

I have a `#define USEWINDOWS` in the Windows API main.cpp file

I don't have this defined in the console app

In the DLL, I would like to do an `#ifdef USEWINDOWS` statement, but the scope of the #define seems to be only valid to the Win32 executable, not in the dll.

How can I extend this #define to the DLL without having it affect the undefined USEWINDOWS in the console app?

Thanks

Comment: There are no `#define`s persisted in `dll`s, or any of the compiled code. It is merely textual replacement, done by pre-processor, before the compilation of the code even begins.

Comment: Could you show your code? Preferably in the form of a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The DLL is shared by both executables, hence there is only one implementation available and therefore you can't use implementation specific compilation flags.

You'll need a runtime flag, i.e. some API parameter which tells the DLL code that it is OK to use "windows stuff". E.g.

api.h

```
void someAPI(...., bool useWindows);
```

dll.c

```
#include "api.h"

void someAPI(...., bool useWindows) {
  ...
  if (useWindows) {
     // do "windows stuff" here
  }
  ...
}
```

app.c

```
#include "api.h"
...
someAPI(...., true);
```

console.c

```
#include "api.h"
...
someAPI(...., false);
```

(not tested by compilation, but you should get the drift...)